# Centos server no longer logging to /var/log/secure after using Nano.

Tags: centos

I used Nano to access the secure log since I had found Fail2ban is no longer working. I didn't make any changes but simply exited the file. Now logging to that file has stopped at the exact time I accessed the file.

I've rebooted the server twice since then but still the logging has stopped on 16:30 yesterday.

Why has this happened?

Comment: Perhaps you have inadvertently changed the permissions (or SELinux context?) of the file. What does `ls -lhZ /var/log/secure` and `sestatus` say. I would also recommend using `less` or something similarly read-only when viewing logs. `nano` is kinda dangerous in my (admittedly dated) experience (`nano -w` is much safer when looking at config files especially).

Comment: @CameronKerr Permissiong are `-rw------- root root ?` and sestatus says disabled. Thanks!

Comment: Odd that even a reboot didn't resolve it. How about forcing a log rotation using `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf`  (check using the manual page that -f will do a force though). If you do something like a login, then you should see that new entries in the file. You might also look for other reasons it might fail (eg. do `df -h /var/log/` or `df -hi /var/log/` show using at 100%). Failing that, you might check that your syslog (rsyslogd / syslogd) is still running. What version of ContOS are you using?

Comment: I used your logrotate command and the secure file is now empty. I'm getting 1000+ failed login attempts every hour but that file has remained blank. CentOS 7.2. 18% space used also. The server did stop working yesterday and apache errors said out of memory, but the memory and disk weren't being used much. The restart fixed that anyway.

Comment: Turn your attention to the configuration of your logging. What is in /etc/syslogd.conf or /etc/rsyslogd.conf?  Also check the configuration of /etc/ssh/sshd_config and your fail2ban and show what the logging configuration is for that. What does `ls -lh /dev/log` show?

Comment: @CameronKerr The log files are all original. This used to work fine until the server ran into problems and I rebooted it (after looking at the log in nano). Fail2ban should be working fine, it's just the secure log is always empty now so it can't read the failed attempts. This morning we've had 16,000 failed login attempts. I'll see if there is any log for rsyslog.

Comment: Not the log, but the log configuration. How do you know you had 16,000 failed login attempts if you don't have the log file? You don't know the cause of the outage, so there is scope that something has changed without your knowing it (perhaps one of the password attempts worked and you've now been broken into).

Comment: I can see the failed login attempts when I first login. I also use `lastb` to check failed login attempts. Sorry I meant the configuration files are original files, never changed. The passwords are 15+ characters long, there is no way they would be bruteforced this century! Especially at the slow speed.

Comment: A few tests to try: use the `logger` command to send some tests cases (authpriv facility and others). Attach to your syslog server using strace to see if it is encountering errors receiving  data or writing to disk. If it's not receiving logs, then try using strace on sshd to see if it's emitting logs. Logger command will be useful when testing that too.

Comment: Logger isn't logging to it. I made a change to the rsyslog.conf file and made it so more things log into the secure log. It is logging things like service restarts. Just nothing to do with auth.

Comment: Post your rsyslog.conf

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you re-create or mess with `/var/log/secure` file. This will break file permissions, especially if SELinux is enabled.

Do the following:

Make sure `/var/log/secure` is owned by `root:root`

```
$ sudo chown root:root /var/log/secure
```

Make sure the permission is set to `600`

```
$ sudo chmod 600 /var/log/secure
```

If SELinux is enabled, you can temporarily disable while troubleshooting your issue

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

If you decide to keep SELinux enabled, make sure the file has the following context:

```
$ ls -lZh /var/log/secure
system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0
```

To manipulate SELinux on the fly (copy context from an existing known working):

```
$ sudo chcon --reference /var/log/dmesg /var/log/secure
```

To manipulate SELinux context permanently, use the [semanage](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) command instead.

Comment: I'd rather use `restorecon` to reset the context and `ausearch -m avc -i` to troubleshoot. Disabling SELinux isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in this same situation recently. The fix is quite simple, restart the `rsyslog` service:

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

This will recreate the `/var/log/secure` file and re-enable logging.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try (despite this being a problem for nearly 5 years now).